# Generlized linear model after multiple imputation on survey data

Tags: regression, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, multiple-imputation, survey-weights

I am using a generalized linear mixed model after multiple imputation on survey data. However, after performing the analysis, I cannot extract random effects and confidence intervals for the estimates. I am using the following code:

```
library(survey)
library(mitools)
library(lme4)
data(nhanes)

# Set up the survey design object
dclus <- svydesign(id = ~SDMVPSU, strata = ~SDMVSTRA, weights = ~WTMEC2YR, data = nhanes, nest = TRUE)

# Impute missing values using MICE
library(mice)
set.seed(123)
imp <- mice(nhanes, m = 5, maxit = 5)

# Fit the generalized linear mixed-effects regression model with survey weights
fit <- with(imp, svyglmer(BPXSY1 ~ RIDAGEYR + RIAGENDR + (1 | SDMVPSU), family = gaussian, weights = WTMEC2YR, design = dclus))

confint(fit)

ranef_fit <- ranef(fit)
summary(ranef_fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your primary problem is that there isn't  any function `svyglmer` in the packages you have loaded (or, to the best of my knowledge and Google, anywhere else). Do you need to run a mixed model -- that is, are you specifically interested in inference about the variance components, or do you just want to account for clustering, which you can do with `survey::svyglm`?

There are other secondary coding problems: I'm not sure whether you're trying to use `with.mids` from `mice` or `with.imputationList` from `mitools` or `with.svyimputationList` from `survey`, but the coding isn't right for any of those.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I want to account for clustering. fRegarding the secondery coding problem I am using with from mice package.

Comment: Ok, then just use `svyglm` and don't specify any random effects.  You'll need to work out how to use `with.mids` -- I don't know and it's off-topic here.  You could try StackOverflow for the coding aspects.